# How to make window overlay (on top of browser,games exc.) with wxPython

Tags: python-3.x, windows, wxpython, overlay

I want to make a simple program (this code is a demo), that will collect system data and display it on top of everything. My goal is to create an overall ping *collector* for the current biggest internet user.

All I'm asking for is how to make a overlay nothing more.

```
"""
Hello World, but with more meat.
"""

import wx

class HelloFrame(wx.Frame):
"""
A Frame that says Hello World
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    # ensure the parent's __init__ is called
    super(HelloFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    # create a panel in the frame
    pnl = wx.Panel(self)

    # and put some text with a larger bold font on it
    st = wx.StaticText(pnl, label="Hello World!", pos=(25,25))
    font = st.GetFont()
    font.PointSize += 10
    font = font.Bold()
    st.SetFont(font)

    # create a menu bar
    self.makeMenuBar()

    # and a status bar
    self.CreateStatusBar()
    self.SetStatusText("Welcome to wxPython!")


def makeMenuBar(self):
    """
    A menu bar is composed of menus, which are composed of menu items.
    This method builds a set of menus and binds handlers to be called
    when the menu item is selected.
    """

    # Make a file menu with Hello and Exit items
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    # The "\t..." syntax defines an accelerator key that also triggers
    # the same event
    helloItem = fileMenu.Append(-1, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
            "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item")
    fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
    # When using a stock ID we don't need to specify the menu item's
    # label
    exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)

    # Now a help menu for the about item
    helpMenu = wx.Menu()
    aboutItem = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT)

    # Make the menu bar and add the two menus to it. The '&' defines
    # that the next letter is the "mnemonic" for the menu item. On the
    # platforms that support it those letters are underlined and can be
    # triggered from the keyboard.
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")
    menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&Help")

    # Give the menu bar to the frame
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

    # Finally, associate a handler function with the EVT_MENU event for
    # each of the menu items. That means that when that menu item is
    # activated then the associated handler function will be called.
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnHello, helloItem)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit,  exitItem)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, aboutItem)


def OnExit(self, event):
    """Close the frame, terminating the application."""
    self.Close(True)


def OnHello(self, event):
    """Say hello to the user."""
    wx.MessageBox("Hello again from wxPython")


def OnAbout(self, event):
    """Display an About Dialog"""
    wx.MessageBox("This is a wxPython Hello World sample",
                  "About Hello World 2",
                  wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # When this module is run (not imported) then create the app, the
    # frame, show it, and start the event loop.
    app = wx.App()
    frm = HelloFrame(None, title='Hello World 2')
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**And this is my code so far for the ping collecting "it is still in progress of making and obviously I'll have to modify it a bit + a lot of optimizing.
The topic is on overlay not on this code.**

```
import os
x= os.system('netstat -on > log.txt')
dat = open('log.txt','r')
line = dat.readlines()
dat.close()
list = []
line = line[4:] #removes irrelevant stuff

for x in line:
    y = ' '.join(x.split())
    if y != '':
        list.append(y)  #y[1:] tcp irrelevant but i'll keep it
for x in range(len(list)):
    list[x] = list[x].split(' ')

top = 0
for x in range(len(list)):
    count = 0
    for y in range(len(list)):
        if list[x][4] == list[y][4]:
            count= count+1
    if count > top:
        top = count
        ip = list[x]

ip = ''.join(ip[2].partition(':')[:1])

os.system('ping '+ip+' -n 3 > log.txt') # -n 3 repeat ping 3 times

dat = open('log.txt','r')
ping = dat.readlines()
dat.close()
ping = ping[len(ping)-1:]

print('Ping for ip: '+ip+' '+' '.join(ping[0].split()))
os.system('del log.txt') #useless stuff
input('')
```

Comment: Do you want a transparent overlay?

Comment: yes - just to display numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://hasenj.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/making-a-fancy-window-in-wxpython/) link is a good tutorial for frame styling/transparent overlays. Here is my favorite code from the tutorial, in which you make a transparent, movable, gray overlay:

```
import wx

class FancyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        style = ( wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR |
                  wx.NO_BORDER | wx.FRAME_SHAPED  )
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Fancy', style = style)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouse)
        self.SetTransparent( 220 )
        self.Show(True)

    def OnKeyDown(self, event):
        """quit if user press q or Esc"""
        if event.GetKeyCode() == 27 or event.GetKeyCode() == ord('Q'): #27 is Esc
            self.Close(force=True)
        else:
            event.Skip()

    def OnMouse(self, event):
        """implement dragging"""
        if not event.Dragging():
            self._dragPos = None
            return
        self.CaptureMouse()
        if not self._dragPos:
            self._dragPos = event.GetPosition()
        else:
            pos = event.GetPosition()
            displacement = self._dragPos - pos
            self.SetPosition( self.GetPosition() - displacement )

app = wx.App()
f = FancyFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Here is the output of the code:

[image: Fancy transparent overlay]

**PS: The code window won't show in the TaskBar**

Comment: Thank you. It's just what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem! Good luck!