# Making a game overlay in python

Tags: python, overlay

So I am trying to make a python script that when I do a certain hotkey combination, It shows a text box as an overlay like what "Geforce Experience" and "Windows Gamebar" do.
the problem is that in the game when I interact with the text-area loses focus and goes minimized as opposed to the 2 programs I spoke about before, for example windows game bar allows you interact with a lot of options while the game is still on foreground and you close the bar you are left with whatever you were with before...
I'm using tkinter for now, and if there are solution not including tkinter it is Ok as long as it achives the goal.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503994/how-to-make-window-overlay-on-top-of-browser-games-exc-with-wxpython) help?

Comment: thanks but nope, it doesn't ...
the problem is that the window appears normally and it functions as expected with the apps, but for games it appears except when clicked ( game focus lost) the game minimize

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: my code wouldn't be private so here is it all : [link](https://gist.github.com/Mahfoudh94/8da4c081867d8b6e192b48d42913236f)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you are trying to do is create a overlay for a game and the overlay should be created using tkinter object. [Here](https://pypi.org/project/overlay/) is a library that can do that, however as far as I remember you needed to change something in it's python file, however this might have already been fixed.

Comment: thanks for this approach, but this is the same as the software I made except instead of making the overlay with tkinter, it make is it easier, but still not the fix for the problem